# Calculate the radius of convergence of $S(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{n^2+4n+3}{5n(n+2)})^n \cdot x^n$

Tags: limits, power-series

I have troubles finding the radius of convergence with the ratio-test, as the terms get pretty large:

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left |\frac{\left(\frac{(n+1)^2+4(n+1)+3}{5(n+1)((n+1)+2)}\right)^{n+1}\cdot x^n}{\left(\frac{n^2+4n+3}{5n(n+2)}\right)^n}\right |$$

So, is there a better way to find the radius?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplying the $n-$th root test you can find that $R=\frac{1}{\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{a_n}}=5$

Answer (score 3):

Use *Hadamard's formula* :
$$\frac1R=\limsup_{n\to+\infty}a_n^{\tfrac 1n}==\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n^2+4n+3}{5n(n+2)}.$$